# Clearing a Singleton object between MVC sessions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, singleton

I have an MVC web application that uses a Singleton object to get and store user identity information once.  This object is stored as part of the model class.

Everything works fine when I'm running locally in Debug mode.  It loads the Singleton at startup and when I exit and run again, it reloads.  I assume this is because IIS express clears everything when the process exits.

When I publish to an actual web server, however, it loads the Singleton and seems to keep it around, even if I exit the website and return later.  I'm not sure if this is because of caching or session information is being retained.

Can someone explain a good way to load data once but force it to be cleared on exit?  I'm having difficulty understanding the scope and lifetime of data in an MVC application.

Thanks.

Comment: Asking for an off-site resource is off-topic, and will get your question closed. I recommend editing your question so it asks a particular thing that can be answered here (i.e. edit your last paragraph).

Comment: Singleton and "Stateless Http" don't go together ! Are you talking about caching data ? Why not use the builtin caching classes (Ex : MemoryCache etc) ?